# Wifi dropping on load

Tags: wireless, wifi, raspbian-wheezy

I did a fresh install of Wheezy and setup my Pi's to connect with WPA, it works fine but after a while the wireless drops. Seems to be during wifi load aswell as well.

I have 2 identical Raspberry Pi setups with identical Wifi devices.

```
fenlig@Green ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

I am using a 1000ma power supply and have tried a 2000ma which made no difference.

if i do a ifup it says its alread configured and a ifdown then a ifup fixes it.

```
fenlig@Green ~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:87:30:23:20:78
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks Fenlig

Comment: what wifi adapters are you using?

Comment: Try this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46569&p=386668 - @JoshuaBurns , one of the outputs show `Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter`...

Comment: Hmm im getting the Power Management:off but its still happening :(

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with exactly the same issue a few months ago. I have tried almost everything, super-ultra efficient power supplies as well. Dying of desperation I changed... **USB power cable**. Since then not a single problem appeared. The cords inside the original one were simply too thin to carry enough current.

P.S.: While searching the answer for my case, I run across plenty of power noise related threads. Be sure to check the whole setup in the different electrical environment.

Comment: I hope thats not the case but I will have to give it a try. While I hunt for a new cable to try is there anyway I can find logs for wireless activity?

Comment: Does `dmesg` give you any output on your wifi dongle? You can also check the `/var/log/` directory, esp. files: `deamon.log` & `kernel.log` for any `NetworkManager` lines.